# How to check if an email is part of a conversation?

Tags: python-3.x, outlook, win32com

Our company has a Customer Service (CS) process where after a client reports an error with our software, we'll get an email about their complain with generic subject ("User Submitted Error") and short description of the error. We then fix the problem and email back to client. An issue may have 1, or multiple emails back and forth between our CS department and client.

My python scrip used `win32com` module to pull emails from Outlook and put them into dataframe, each row as an entry for a unique reported error. After reading (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.mailitem.conversationid), I decided to go with `message.ConversationID`. However, the generic email subject means sometimes they would group all unrelated emails together, make `ConversationID` not really that unique nor useful to me.

Can someone provide me some guide on how best to tackle this issue?

```
outlook = win32com.client.Dispatch('Outlook.Application').GetNamespace('MAPI')

def message_to_row(message, year, start_month, end_month): # Process each email into row of information
    message_time = message.ReceivedTime
    winrec_time = message.ReceivedTime
    rec_time = pywintypes.Time(winrec_time) 
    rec_year = rec_time.year
    rec_month = rec_time.month
    rec_day = rec_time.day
    rec_time_string = str(rec_time.hour) + ":" + str(rec_time.minute)
    rec_time = format(datetime.datetime.strptime(rec_time_string, "%H:%M"), "%H:%M")

    if rec_year >= year:
        if rec_month in range(start_month, end_month):
            convo_id = message.ConversationID
            message_body = message.body.replace("_", " ")
            row = [convo_id, rec_year, rec_month, 
                   rec_day, rec_time, message_body]              
    return row
```

Comment: Emails are not guaranteed to have a ConversionID assigned. Most companies I've worked with get around this issue by simply including the support case number somewhere in their email content, like at the top of the body, or in the subject, and they require customers to include the case number when replying back.

Comment: Thank for your input @RemyLebeau, but I am working with old emails from last year. I'd probably ask CS to do that in the future to avoid this headache.